# Calculation of two cells in a COUNTIF

Tags: excel, countif

I have an Excel document with two date columns and a column with four possible values. I need to filter for one value on the last column. Then I need to calculate the days between the two dates for all the values that are left and count the times that those days are between `0` and `30`.

I know how to filter and I know how to calculate the days between two dates. I also know how to count the times those days are between `0` and `30`.

I cannot figure out how to put it all together without making a simple calculation in another sheet and hide it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding. It is no longer necessary though. I forgot to close this question.

Answer (score -1):

No longer needed. I found out how to pull the data from Google Analytics with some VBA code.